# minimization on sphere

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, optimization

Let $\mathbf{z}=(z_1,\cdots,z_n)$ be a point in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Assume that $z_j=x_j+\iota 
y_j$. Let $d\ge 3$. We want to maximize $x_1^2$ such that

\begin{align}
  & \sum_{j=1}^n z_j^d=0, \\ 
  & \sum_{j=1}^n|z_j|^2=1.
\end{align}

Note that if $d$ is odd, then the maximum value is $\frac{1}{2}$.

> As we know if $\sum_{j=1}^n z_j^d=0$ and $d$ is odd, then $z_l+z_k=0$ for some $l$ and $k$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2397468/the-sum-of-odd-powered-complex-numbers-equals-zero-implies-they-cancel-each-othe)).

Now I am stuck what happens if $d$ is even. Any hint will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: $z_1^3+z_2^3=0$ doesn't imply $z_1+z_2=0$ (see $z_1=1, z_2=e^{i\pi/3}$); the result you quote is if the sum of odd powers is zero for all the odd powers, not for a specific one

Comment: what you want to do is use that $x_1^2 \le |z_1|^2 \le (\sum_{k \ge 2}|z_k|^d)^{2/d} \le \sum_{k \ge 2}|z_k|^2$ (here one needs $d \ge 2$) to conclude the maximum is $1/2$ attained for $z_1=1/\sqrt 2, z_2=\alpha/\sqrt 2,z_3=z_4=..=z_n=0, \alpha^d=-1$ so for $d$ odd you can take $z_2=-z_1$ indeed

Comment: @Conrad, you are right. Now I realized it. Thanks for your help.