# An alternative lower bound for $\prod_{ i,j = 1}^n\frac{1+a_ia_j}{1-a_ia_j} $

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, alternative-proof

In [Prove that $\prod_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\frac{1+a_ia_j}{1-a_ia_j}\geq1$ for $n$ real numbers $a_i\in(-1,1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4667195/42969) it was shown that for real numbers $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in (-1, 1)$ we always have
$$
 P = \prod_{ i,j = 1}^n\frac{1+a_ia_j}{1-a_ia_j} \ge 1 \, .
$$
The proof (originally from [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6h3033542_nice_but_difficult)) uses the Taylor series of the logarithm to derive an explicit formula for the logarithm of that product as an infinite sum of squares with positive coefficients:
$$ \tag{*}
 \ln P = 2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2k-1} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^{2k-1}\right)^2 \ge 0 \, .
$$

If we omit all terms for $k \ge 2$ on the right-hand side then we get the weaker inequality
$$ \tag 1
 \ln P \ge 2 ( a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n)^2 
$$
or equivalently
$$ \tag 2
 P \ge e^{2( a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n)^2 }
$$

**My question:** Is there a simpler/more direct way to obtain $(1)$ or $(2)$ without the use of infinite series?

We cannot use
$$
 \ln(1+a_ia_j) - \ln(1-a_ia_j) \ge 2 a_i a_j
$$
because that holds only if $a_ia_j \ge 0$. Another idea is to consider the function
$$
 f(x) = \prod_{ i,j = 1}^n\frac{1+x^2a_ia_j}{1-x^2a_ia_j} \, .
$$
for $0 \le x \le 1$. From the representation $(*)$ we know that $\ln f(x)$ is increasing in $x$, but it is not obvious (to me) how to prove that directly, since the terms in
$$
 \frac{d}{dx} \ln f(x) = \sum_{i, j=1}^n \frac{4a_i a_j x}{1-a_i^2a_j^2 x^4}
$$
can be both positive and negative.

Comment: One remark: the proof only uses the fact that $\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)$ has nonnegative Maclaurin series coefficients (and that the series has radius of convergence at least $1$, I guess), and so the result holds with $\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)$ replaced by any function $f(x)$ with the same property.

Comment: @GregMartin More generally, a series with radius of convergence $R$ allows for any $a_i$ of modulus less than $\sqrt{R}$.

Comment: An "obvious" reason why it is true: - if exactly $k$ of the $n$ numbers are negative then there are $k^2+(n-k)^2$ factors that are $\geq 1$ and $2k(n-k)$ are $\leq 1$ and since AM-GM says $k^2+(n-k)^2\geq 2k(n-k),$ the whole product is $\geq 1. $

Comment: @dezdichado Following your remark can we show it using https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4244874/can-we-prove-am-gm-inequality-using-these-integrals

Comment: @ErikSatie I don't see how that will be applicable. Essentially, for an odd, increasing on $f$ that is  convex on$[0,1)$ and concave on $(-1,0],$ we can use Karamata to conclude if we can show that it is possible to extract $2k(n-k)$ of the positive terms that can majorize  the negatives. I checked manually for $n=3,4$ but it's ugly, case-by-case solution.

Comment: @dezdichado OK . See my answer/Draft there is a point i cannot justify completely can you help me to find it ?

Answer (score 4):

We have the base case of $1+a_1^2 \ge 1-a_1^2$ for $a_1 \in (-1,1)$

Now suppose we have $P = \prod_{ (i,j) \in A} (1+a_ia_j) \ge \prod_{ (i,j) \in A} (1-a_ia_j) \, $ for some nonempty $A \subsetneq \{1..n\}\times\{1..n\}$

Let $(i_0,j_0),(i_1,j_1) \in \{1..n\}\times\{1..n\} - A$,

Now

$$\begin{aligned}P &= \prod_{ (i,j) \in A} (1+a_ia_j) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{|A|} \sum_{S \subset A}^{|S| = k} C_S \prod_{ (i,j) \in S} a_ia_j\\
\end{aligned}$$

Where $C_S = \{ \# $ ways to get a permute of $S$ from $ A\}$

And

$$\begin{aligned}Q &= \prod_{ (i,j) \in A} (1-a_ia_j) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{|A|} \sum_{S \subset A}^{|S| = k} (-1)^k\ C_S \prod_{ (i,j) \in S} a_ia_j\\
\end{aligned}$$

Then $$\begin{aligned}\frac{P-Q}{2} &= \sum_{\substack{
   k=1 \\
   k\ odd
  }}^{|A|} \sum_{S \subset A}^{|S| = k} C_S \prod_{ (i,j) \in S} a_ia_j
\end{aligned}$$

Calling the above expression $I(A)$, our inequality is equivalent to $I(A) \ge 0$

Now considering the inductive case $A' = A\cup \{(i_0,j_0)\}\cup \{(i_1,j_1)\}$

$$\begin{align}I(A') &= \sum_{\substack{
   k=1 \\
   k\ odd
  }}^{|A|+2} \sum_{\substack{
   S \subset A
   &\cup \{(i_0,j_0)\}\\
     &\cup \{(i_1,j_1)\}
  }}^{|S| = k} C_S \prod_{ (i,j) \in S} a_ia_j \\\\
&= \sum_{\substack{
   k=1 \\
   k\ odd
  }}^{|A|} \ \sum_{\substack{T \subset \{&(i_0,j_0),&(i_1,j_1)\} }} \ \Biggl( \biggl[\prod_{ (i,j) \in T} a_ia_j \biggr] \Biggl( \ \sum_{S \subset A }^{|S| = k} \biggl[ C_S \prod_{ (i,j) \in S} a_ia_j \biggr] \  \Biggr) \Biggr)
\end{align}$$

In other words

$$\begin{align}
I(A') &= I(A) + I(A \cup \{(i_0,j_0)\}) + I(A \cup \{(i_1,j_1)\}) + I(A \cup \{(i_0,j_0), (i_1,j_1)\})\\
&= I(A) + a_{i_0}a_{j_0}I(A) + a_{i_1}a_{j_1}I(A) + a_{i_0}a_{j_0}a_{i_1}a_{j_1}I(A) \\
&= (1 + a_{i_0}a_{j_0} + a_{i_1}a_{j_1} + a_{i_0}a_{j_0}a_{i_1}a_{j_1})I(A) \\
&= (1 + a_{i_0}a_{j_0})(1 + a_{i_1}a_{j_1})I(A) \\
&\ge 0
\end{align}$$

And we are done.

Comment: I think induction should work. But why is your particular case of $A'$ to have two more elements than $A$ ? Also, I think OP is looking for a stronger lower bound than just $1$

Comment: $I(A')$ is a sum over odd subsets, adding two elements preserves parity, kind of, I am sweeping under the rug the fact that the middle terms $a_{i_0}a_{j_0}I(A)$ and $a_{i_1}a_{j_1}I(A)$ in the recurrence are actually sums over even subsets. A fully rigorous proof would need induction on both functions.


The lower bound of 1 can't be done away with entirely since it is met when the $a_i$ are $0$, but this proof, when corrected, constructs the precise value of their difference.

Comment: Is this a proof of $P = \prod_{ i,j = 1}^n\frac{1+a_ia_j}{1-a_ia_j} \ge 1 $ or a proof of $ P \ge e^{2( a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n)^2 }$? – The latter is what my question is about: *“Is there a simpler/more direct way to obtain (1) or (2) ...”*

Answer (score 1):

Draft :

Let $-1<x<1$ then define :

$$f\left(x\right)=\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$$

then we have :

$$f'''\left(x\right)>0$$

Then the idea is to use Levinson's inequalities see https://rgmia.org/papers/v15/v15a68.pdf

Example case $n=2$ we have $x,a\in(-1,1),c=0 $:

$$f\left(a^{2}+c\right)+f\left(b^{2}+c\right)+2f\left(ab+c\right)-(f\left(-a^{2}-c\right)+f\left(-b^{2}-c\right)+2f\left(-ab-c\right))\geq 4f\left(\frac{\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+2ab+3c\right)}{4}\right)-4f\left(\frac{-\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+2ab+3c\right)}{4}\right)\geq 2(a+b)^2$$

Some explanation :

As we have equality (3) in the linked paper combined to $\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=-\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)$

We can switch the problematic values (not the squares) and the proof of theorem 4 is the same .

Remains to show the last hand side .

We are done .

Edit :

Fuch 's inequality works because  it the vector (a^2,b^2,2ab) majorize the vector in the other side.But the argument above is still incomplete

Comment: We can tackle it with $a_ia_j-c_{i,j}-a_ia_j+c_{i,j}=0,c_{i,j}>0$ in rearranging the positive and the negative $a_ia_j$ such that  $\min(\cdots)\leq \max(\cdots)$ and we can use theorem 2

Comment: @MartinR I show the  case $n=2$ can you proceed further ?

Comment: @MartinR I wait you .It works due to the symmetry we can remove the constraint $\max\leq \min $ .