# Inequality involving quadratic forms for positive definite symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, quadratic-forms, symmetric-matrices

Suppose that for a given fixed $v$, and two positive definite symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$ (with real-valued entries) it holds that:
$$
v^T A v > v^T B v.
$$
Does it then hold that
$$
v^T A^{-1} v < v^T B^{-1} v
$$
for the same $v$?

Context: I am working with some inequalities involving quadratic forms of the form $v^TA^{-1}v$ where $A$ is the expected value of a matrix-valued random variable. I can bound the expectation $v^TAv$ both above and below but not its inverse so easily, so if I could get rid of the inversion it would be helpful, but I'm not convinced that I can. Of course there may also be another way to approach problem.

What I have tried: I considered some basic approaches using spectral decompositions of $A$ and $B$ but since the eigenvectors can be different I didn't get very far. I am not, however, very experienced in this area. I also tried to find a simple counterexample among 2 x 2 matrices. I couldn't but that does not mean that there isn't one!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Perhaps related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4677765/prove-or-disprove-the-following-generalization-sum-i-j-1nf-lefta-ia/4678471#4678471

Comment: suppose you had two symmetric $3\times 3$ matrices each with the same eigenvalues of $\big\{\lambda, 1, \lambda^{-1}\big\}$ and with $\big \Vert \mathbf v \big\Vert =1$ you could have the case where the first quadratic form  $=\frac{1}{2}\big(\lambda + \lambda^{-1}\big)$ and the second one equal $=1 \cdot 1$, then $ \mathbf v^T A^{-1}\mathbf v=\mathbf v^T A\mathbf v\gt 1 = \mathbf v^T B\mathbf v=\mathbf v^T B^{-1}\mathbf v$.  Supposing you know spectral theorem, you should be able to fill in the details to make this an explicit counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct. Try $n=2$ and $A=I_2$ and $B$ diagonal.